# App Getting Crash while Continuous open and close Activity between 2 activities

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-activity, android-recyclerview

My Android App having multiple activities, now my problem is unable to findable.

A Activity have one recyclerView it get data from local database, If I click the items it will open B Activity, this same flow continuously then app getting crash(like open B Activity come back to A Activity and open again B activity- up to 5 to 6 time do same action then app getting crash)

The Crash message is related to `SQLite` DATABASE but unable to find where it occurs. Please help me... already spend more time for this...

> Note: open DB on Oncreate and Close DB on OnDestroy in both activities

**Error Message**

```
E/SQLiteQuery: exception: unable to open database file (code 14); query: SELECT DISTINCT * FROM parameters WHERE inspection_no LIKE '%TEST-123%'
E/InputChannel-JNI: Error 24 dup channel fd 1023.
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.testapp.testprocess, PID: 13078
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not read input channel file descriptors from parcel.
                      at android.view.InputChannel.nativeReadFromParcel(Native Method)
                      at android.view.InputChannel.readFromParcel(InputChannel.java:148)
                      at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.addToDisplay(IWindowSession.java:841)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:640)
                      at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:342)
                      at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:94)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3518)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2733)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1478)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
```

Comment: I think you forget to close db object after completing the task. try close it..

Comment: @AdarshAshok, No, open DB on Oncreate and Close DB on OnDestroy in both activities

Comment: please close the db after completing the task... it may resolve your issue

Comment: close the dp connection on OnPause()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by the following steps.

1. I have created Singleton Database, so it ensures the database object created only once.
2. Closing cursor object after querying the database. **(I missed it)**
3. Closing the database in onStop() of an activity. **(I read onDestroy() is not safe, it won't be called for sure)**

Thanks to all for the timely help :)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever we access or update database we should have to open and close database after operation is performed. have look.

```
DataBaseHelper db = new DataBaseHelper(this);
db.open();
Cursor cursor = db.getAllItems(); 
maxCount = cursor.getCount(); 
Random gen = new Random();
row = gen.nextInt(maxCount); 
 if (cursor.moveToPosition(row)) {
    String myString = cursor.getString(1);
}
cursor.close();
db.close();
```

here is `getAllItems()` which will return items.

```
public Cursor getAllItems() 
{
return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
        KEY_ROWID, 
        KEY_NAME
        }, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null);
}
```

so in your case, when you click on list item you have to open/close database carefully.

Happy coding!!

Answer (score 1):

Try using Singleton pattern and access using db=DatabaseHelper.getInstance(context).It guarantees that only one database helper will exist across the entire application lifecycle.

```
 public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper { 

 private static DatabaseHelper sInstance;

 private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database_name";
 private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "table_name";
 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

 public static synchronized DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context) {

  // Use the application context, which will ensure that you 
  // don't accidentally leak an Activity's context.
  if (sInstance == null) {
     sInstance = new DatabaseHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
  }
    return sInstance;
  }

  /**
    * Constructor should be private to prevent direct instantiation.
    * make call to static method "getInstance()" instead.
    */
     private DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
           super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs when you forget to close the database.
try closing the cursor and database after the transaction.